# C# Updating mysql rows between two dates

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 c# using MySql Data Connector (Current Version).
I have tried just about every command I can think of... Now I seem to be stuck.

```
MySqlConnection connectionA = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand commandA = connectionA.CreateCommand();
connectionA.Open();
MySqlDataReader Reader;

commandA.CommandText = "UPDATE trips SET vanid=null WHERE vanid='4' AND tripdate BETWEEN '2014-09-06' AND '2050-12-31'";
connectionA.Close();
```

When I try this command, I get no errors or does it update the database.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: After you set the CommandText, you forgot to run it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is never executing the command and sending it to the database.

```
commandA.CommandText = "UPDATE trips SET vanid=null WHERE vanid='4' AND tripdate BETWEEN '2014-09-06' AND '2050-12-31'";
commandA.ExecuteNonQuery();
connectionA.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked great. I tried to give 1 up but I am still a newbie....

Comment: For now just mark an answer as correct. You'll get the up vote ability later.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever executing the query :) You need...

```
commandA.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked great. I tried to give 1 up but I am still a newbie....